# Image src not updating after setRequestHeader call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two AJAX functions: one for an image file upload, one for a form info upload.

**File Upload**

```
function uploadFile(insertNodeID, inputFileID){

var img = document.getElementById(inputFileID).files[0];

var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file[]', img, img.name);

var objXML = new XMLHttpRequest();
objXML.onprogress = updateProgress; 

objXML.onload = function() {
    if(objXML.readyState==4 && objXML.status==200) {

        if(objXML.responseText !== 'no'){
            document.getElementById(insertNodeID).src = objXML.responseText;
        }
        else{
            errorInOut('There was a problem uploading the file.');
        }
    }
};

objXML.open('POST', baseURL+'ajax/admin_fileupload/', true);
objXML.send(form_data);
```

**Form Info Upload**

```
function uploadFormInfo(strURL, strData, type) {

strURL = baseURL+'ajax/'+strURL+'/';

var objXML = new XMLHttpRequest();

objXML.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (objXML.readyState == 4 && objXML.status == 200) {
        returnXML(objXML.responseText, type);
    }
};

objXML.open("POST", strURL, true);
objXML.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
objXML.send(strData);
```

They both work perfect independently.

The issue I'm running into is when I call the uploadFormInfo(), then call uploadFile(), the document.getElementById(insertNodeID).src does not render the uploaded image. It still uploads the image to the server and the responseText is the correct path to the image. I did a console.log on the .src of the id AFTER the I plugged in the new image and the .src is correct BUT, it never changes in the elements tab in Chome inspect. It also works fine BEFORE I call uploadFormInfo().

I've tried and number of things (sending a separate request header for the uploadFile) and nothing works.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Does `objXML.responseText` at `uploadFile` function render the image when the URL is visited in a new tab? What is `strData`?

Comment: strData is the serialized form data. Yeah, the objXML.responseText returns the absolute path to the image in both uses cases (before uploadFormInfo is called and after uploadFormInfo is called) but for some reason after uploadFormInfo is called, the .src will not update. It's odd. I don't get it.